# Showing that a stochastic process does not converge

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am a non-mathematician trying to apply stochastic calculus. I have have a process $X_t$ taking values in $[0,\infty)$. It is defined by

\begin{equation}
X_t=exp\left(\int_{0}^{t}\Theta(u)dW(u)\right),
\end{equation}

where $\int_{0}^{t}\Theta(u)dW(u)$ is a stochastic integral. $\Theta_t$ is also stochastic but its values are determined by the Wiener process $W_t$. How can I show (or what assumptions do I need to impose on $\Theta_t$ to guarantee)  that the process does not converge almost surely as $t\rightarrow \infty$ to $0$ (or any other number). Moreover, how to show that it does not approach infinity, for example that there is a bound $K$ such that

$Prob(X_t<K)>0$ $\forall t$.

Comment: I guess, if the process in the exponent is square integrable then it is a martingale. Then it is sufficient to show the result for any martingale.